# jQuery debounce function not firing

Tags: jquery, throttling

I'm trying to get my search suggestion element to fire the ajax call 300ms after the last keystroke, here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.textSearch').keyup($.debounce(searchSuggest() {

}, 300));
```

I've tested the Ajax function itself and it works fine if I just add an onkeyup="searchSuggest()" onto my text input, which has the class textSearch. But using this debounce function I found with some google searches, it doesn't fire anything. Help!

Comment: You should at least mention what plugin you are using. Based on the syntax, I am guessing it is Ben Alman's implementation, http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.textSearch').keyup( $.debounce(300, seatchSuggest) );
```